# Оптимизация SQL-запроса

Tags: оптимизация, sql

Как оптимизировать запрос, а то превышает ожидание?

```
select distinct e2.[Номер],  e3.[ФИО],  convert( char, [Показание] ) as [Показание]  
from [stack].[Лицевые счета] e2,
     [stack].[!ПоказанияСчетчиков] g, 
     [stack].[!ОбщиеДанные] e3 
where ( (
e2.[ROW_ID]  not in ( select [idКвитанция] from [stack].[!ПоказанияСчетчиков])) or
   (e3.[id_ls]  not in (select [ROW_ID] from [stack].[Лицевые счета] )))
and
 g.[РасчМес]='2012-03-01 00:00:00'
```

Comment: реально тяжелый =)

Comment: Тут надо явно джойнами делать. А то тройное перемножение... жесть... надо подумать :-) Индексы все что надо есть?

Comment: Имеет смысл описать какая предметная задача ложиться на запрос

Answer (score 1):

Можно для начала сделать что то типа такого:
Так наверное правельние:

```
   select e2.[Номер],  
          e3.[ФИО],  
          convert( char, g.[Показание] ) as [Показание]  
   from [stack].[Лицевые счета] as e2 
   left join [!ОбщиеДанные] as e3 on (e3.[id_ls] = e2.[ROW_ID])
   left join [!ПоказанияСчетчиков]  as g on (g.[idКвитанция]=e2.[ROW_ID])
   where e3.[id_ls] is null or g.[idКвитанция] is null
```

Comment: хотя второе условие в where наверное лишнее

Comment: по-моему здесь нужен full outer join

Comment: А зачем? Тут по идее - нет ФИО - нет проблем, а фул джоин добавить записи без фио, а они нафиг не нужны

Comment: Так точно не нужен оутер джоин